# Ui router Couldn't find views with Nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular-ui-router

I'm working on nodejs application we use the Ui router to implement single page application , I Created the controller in node js that load the Layout which have angular scripts and libraries , and then I tried to navigate throught the routes I defined in ui router , each time I got the error in the console said **`"angular.js:8081 GET http://localhost:2405/Views/Partials/Know-me.html 404 (Not Found)"`**
I can't specify the problem

this is some code :

Nodejs Controller

```
app.get("/",function(req , res){
    res.render("Template.ejs"); // this is the layout
});
```

Layout Scripts :

```
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.8/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../angular_js/app_angular.js"></script>
```

and the app_angular script :

```
var appmodule = angular.module('mainApp',[ui.router]);

 appmodule.config(function($stateProvider , $urlRouterProvider ,   $locationProvider){
     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/things');

     $stateProvider
     .state('me',{
         url : '/me',
         templateUrl :  '/Views/Partials/Know-me.html'
     })
     .state('amir',{
         url : '/amir',
         templateUrl : '/Know-me-amir.html'
     });
     //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
 });
```

structure of the project :

-- View

--- Shared

---- Temaplte.ejs

--- Partials

---- know-me.html

-- Scripts

--- angular_js

---- angular_app.js

Comment: Try to add a . in the begining of the path of your templateUrl. templateUrl : './Know-me-amir.html'. If it does not work can you show us the structure of your project ?

Comment: I added the structure of the project @AnassAnas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:
ejs files are rendered on the server. AngularJS (client) tries to fetch 
'Views/Partials/Know-me.html'. From client's perspective this html does not exist.

**Please do the following:**

1. Add an public folder.
2. Serve the public folder with express.static()
3. Move the html files to this directory: public/Views/Partials/Know-me.html
4. Try to access  http://localhost:2405/Views/Partials/Know-me.html - if you see the contents of know-me - your are good to go!

now your client will find the asyncronisly loaded html file.